# How to read analog input from Arduino using C#

Tags: c#, arduino

I'm new with Arduino, i need to know how can i read the analog input come from sensors to my program using c#,

Example: i have two sensors connected to A0 and A1,

how can i read A0, and A1`separated,

Regrds

Comment: provide some source code of what you have done so far

Comment: Maybe the [CmdMessenger](https://github.com/thijse/Arduino-Libraries/tree/master/CmdMessenger) library for Arduino / C# communication can be a start for you. You can modify the library examples (see http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/CmdMessenger) very simple and adapt it to your needs.